# How do I set mouse-speed to ridiculous levels of slow for digital painting

Tags: command-line, package-management, mouse

Back when Ubuntu was using unity instead of gnome there was a command I used all the time to slow down the mouse to just plain silly levels.

```
Mouse-speed -s 10
```

Setting it to 50 was about normal and 10 made digital art a lot more comfortable. You almost forgot you where using a mouse instead of a pen. Anything below 5 and your mouse might as well have been frozen.
The problem is, for the ife of me, I can't find what package the command belonged to. So far my best guess is something like the unity tweak tool. My brother loved to have loads of customization packages installed. It was often amusing to set the mouse speed so high it was unusable and watch my families reactions.
I have tried a few different methods of changing mouse speed(like xinput) but none of them slow it down to the levels I need to sketch comfortably with a mouse.

Any ideal how I can find packages through the commands they provide?

Is there a package you are aware of that is capable of setting mouse speed to anything from frozen to lightning speed?